# Subscriptions with react-meteor-data

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

From the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer), I wrote my container like so

```
export default InventoryItemsList = createContainer(() => {
  const itemsCollection = Meteor.subscribe('allInventoryItems');
  const loading = !itemsCollection.ready();

  return {
    loading,
    items: !loading ? InventoryItems.find().fetch() : []
  };
}, class InventoryItemsListComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    let items = this.props.items;

    /* some render logic */

    return /*... react component template ...*/ ;
  }
});
```

The problem I see is that

1. The container function is executed many times, thus calling `Meteor.subscribe` more than once; is that good? Will Meteor just ignore subsequent subscriptions?
2. According to [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/mIKYpjmWThU?list=PLDTIzARlzfxQ4OnmGMNiWDEZAfRf3Q7Mr&t=438), subscriptions need to be stopped, but the docs do not mention it at all. This does not take care on it's own, does it?

What is the recommended way to stop (i.e. unsubscribe) or resolve the 2 issues that I see from that point?

Is TrackerRact actually better? *(yes, I know this is opinionated, but surely there is some form of a convention with meteor react, here!)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The container component is a reactive component, so whenever documents are changed or added to the given collection, it's going to call via your container and update the DOM.

2) As far as I know, the container will only subscribe to the collection via the actual component you bind it to. Once you leave that component, the subscriptions should stop.

If you want to unsubscribe directly, you can just call `this.props.items.stop()` in your `componentWillUnmount()` method.

Finally, I will have to say that using React specific implementations are always better than using Meteor specific functions (i.e. it's always better to use state variables over Sessions with React, as it's always better to use containers than Tracker.autorun() with React, etc, etc).

Comment: "the subscriptions should stop" Well, this seems to me like an anti-pattern, as described in Meteor docs. I am not sure that it actually stops magically. What do you mean by "using React specific impleentations" ? Could you be more specific?

Comment: What I mean by React specific implementations is methods and properties that are native to React. For example, it's better to use state variables than it is to use Session variables. React was specifically designed with states, so it's always going to work better for your app using them instead of Session variables or Reactive variables.

Comment: The same with the container for subscriptions. Don't quote me on it, but I believe the container component was designed by MDG for reactivity and an easy way to subscribe to data in your components on Meteor. Therefore, it's always better to use that than Tracker. Not even sure how you would get a tracker to work in this case with React.

Comment: I am lost in your comments. You are talking about session and reactive vars vs states, but your answer does not give an example of what you are proposing; unless I don't understand how this work, states make use of reactive variables, no? What do you mean mean by "React specific implementations" in regards to the code in the question?

Comment: States can be used like you use reactive variables like Sessions or ReactiveVar, therefore there is no use of using Meteor specific implementations like ReactiveVars when it's native in React. That's what I mean.

Comment: There is one difference though and that is that Sessions are not bound locally and you have pretty much global access to Session data. State variables, like ReactiveVars, are to be used locally in a single component or template. Won't work globally.

Comment: @YanickRochon Now I'm not sure if this is concrete evidence since I didn't heavily analyze the code, but you can sort of verify that subscriptions stop when a component unmounts. To do this, go to a view which holds your component, open the browser console and do "console.log(Meteor.connection._subscriptions)." This prints out an array of subscription with their corresponding name properties and you should see your target subscription. If you go to a different screen which does NOT have the target component, and print the same, you should see that your target subscription is no longer there.

Comment: @Simon thank you! This will surely help for testing!

Answer (score 0):

About your problem 2), this is how I solve it

1- When you subscribe to something, store those subscriptions references and pass them to the component.

Here an example with 2 subscriptions, but subscribing to only 1, is even easier.

```
createContainer((props) =>{
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('Publication1', props.param1);
  const subscription2 = Meteor.subscribe('Publication2', props.param1, props.param2);
  const loading = !(subscription.ready() && subscription2.ready());
  const results1 = loading ? undefined : Collection1.find().fetch();
  const results2 = loading ? undefined : Collection2.findOne({a:1});
  return {subscriptions: [subscription, subscription2], loading, results1, results2};
}, MyComp);
```

Then in my component:

```
class MyComp extends Component {
......
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.subscriptions.forEach((s) =>{
      s.stop();
    });
  }
....
}
```

This way, the component will get in `props.subscriptions` all the subscriptions it needs to stop before unmounting.

Also you can use this.props.loading to know if the subscriptions are ready (of course, you can have 2 different ready1 and ready2 if it helps).

Last thing, after subscribing, if you `.find()`, dont forget to `.fetch()`, else the results will not be reactive.

Comment: FWIW I now use [Subscription Manager](https://github.com/kadirahq/subs-manager) for most of my subscriptions. I implemented a subscription manager cache, in order to have access to different managers in different parts of the app, and this seems to work like a charm. I virtually have no need for `createContainer` anymore, and instead use [ListContainer](https://github.com/meteor-utilities/react-list-container) elements.